# Insert search in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, search

I have made todo app, where  you can add, delete, sort tasks and task details. I created ListView and connected with SQLite database.
I want to add search by task name in my app, but I am trying very hard without results.
I wanted to add searh option on apps top(like in menu).
Every variant how I can implement search in my app to find task will be perfect.

My code:
Main code AndroidSQLite.java

```
    package app.androidsqlite;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

          public class AndroidSQLite extends Activity {

EditText inputContent1, inputContent2;
Button buttonAdd, buttonDeleteAll;
Button buttonSortDefault, buttonSort1;

private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
ListView listContent;

SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
Cursor cursor;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    inputContent1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.content1);
    inputContent2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.content2);
    buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    buttonDeleteAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deleteall);

    listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);

    mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

    cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
    String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID, 

   SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT1, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT2};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.text1, R.id.text2};
    cursorAdapter =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
    listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    listContent.setOnItemClickListener(listContentOnItemClickListener);

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(buttonAddOnClickListener);
    buttonDeleteAll.setOnClickListener(buttonDeleteAllOnClickListener);

    buttonSortDefault = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sortbyDefault);
    buttonSort1 =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.sortby1);

    buttonSortDefault.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
            String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID, 
 SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT1, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT2};
            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.text1, R.id.text2};
            cursorAdapter =
                    new SimpleCursorAdapter(AndroidSQLite.this, 
  R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
            listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
            updateList();
        }});

    buttonSort1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll_SortBy_CONTENT1();
            String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID, 
  SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT1, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT2};
            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.text1, R.id.text2};
            cursorAdapter =
                    new SimpleCursorAdapter(AndroidSQLite.this, 
  R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
            listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
            updateList();
        }});


}

   Button.OnClickListener buttonAddOnClickListener
        = new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String data1 = inputContent1.getText().toString();
        String data2 = inputContent2.getText().toString();
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert(data1, data2);
        updateList();
    }

    };

    Button.OnClickListener buttonDeleteAllOnClickListener
        = new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();
        updateList();
    }

     };

    private ListView.OnItemClickListener listContentOnItemClickListener
        = new ListView.OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        final int item_id = 
 cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID));
        String item_content1 = 
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT1));
        String item_content2 = 
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT2));

        AlertDialog.Builder myDialog
                = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidSQLite.this);

        myDialog.setTitle("Delete/Edit?");

        TextView dialogTxt_id = new TextView(AndroidSQLite.this);
        LayoutParams dialogTxt_idLayoutParams
                = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialogTxt_id.setLayoutParams(dialogTxt_idLayoutParams);
        dialogTxt_id.setText("#" + String.valueOf(item_id));

        final EditText dialogC1_id = new EditText(AndroidSQLite.this);
        LayoutParams dialogC1_idLayoutParams
                = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialogC1_id.setLayoutParams(dialogC1_idLayoutParams);
        dialogC1_id.setText(item_content1);

        final EditText dialogC2_id = new EditText(AndroidSQLite.this);
        LayoutParams dialogC2_idLayoutParams
                = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialogC2_id.setLayoutParams(dialogC2_idLayoutParams);
        dialogC2_id.setText(item_content2);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(AndroidSQLite.this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.addView(dialogTxt_id);
        layout.addView(dialogC1_id);
        layout.addView(dialogC2_id);
        myDialog.setView(layout);

        myDialog.setPositiveButton("Delete", new 
  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            // do something when the button is clicked
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                mySQLiteAdapter.delete_byID(item_id);
                updateList();
            }
        });

        myDialog.setNeutralButton("Update", new 
  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            // do something when the button is clicked
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                String value1 = dialogC1_id.getText().toString();
                String value2 = dialogC2_id.getText().toString();
                mySQLiteAdapter.update_byID(item_id, value1, value2);
                updateList();
            }
        });

        myDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new 
  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            // do something when the button is clicked
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            }
        });

        myDialog.show();


    }};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    mySQLiteAdapter.close();
}



private void updateList(){
    cursor.requery();
}
```

}

SQLiteAdapter.java

```
    package app.androidsqlite;


    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

  public class SQLiteAdapter {

public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT1 = "Content1";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT2 = "Content2";

//create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
        "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + KEY_CONTENT1 + " text not null, "
                + KEY_CONTENT2 + " text not null);";

private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

private Context context;

public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
    context = c;
}

public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, 
 MYDATABASE_VERSION);
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, 
   MYDATABASE_VERSION);
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    sqLiteHelper.close();
}

public long insert(String content1, String content2){

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT1, content1);
    contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT2, content2);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
}

public int deleteAll(){
    return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
}

public void delete_byID(int id){
    sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
}

public void update_byID(int id, String v1, String v2){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_CONTENT1, v1);
    values.put(KEY_CONTENT2, v2);
    sqLiteDatabase.update(MYDATABASE_TABLE, values, KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
}

public Cursor queueAll(){
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT1, KEY_CONTENT2};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    return cursor;
}

public Cursor queueAll_SortBy_CONTENT1(){
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT1, KEY_CONTENT2};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
            null, null, null, null, KEY_CONTENT1);

    return cursor;
}

public Cursor queueAll_SortBy_CONTENT2(){
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT1, KEY_CONTENT2};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
            null, null, null, null, KEY_CONTENT2);

    return cursor;
}

public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
                        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
 {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

 }
```

main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pievienojiet nosaukumu"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/content1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pievienojiet detaļas"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/content2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/deleteall"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete All"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sortbyDefault"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sort By default"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sortby1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sort By Content 1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contentlist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:text="#"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:text=":" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:padding="2dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:padding="2dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I know that probablly I need to add searchable.xml file and add some lines in AndroidManifest.xml, but I cant write all sql code and main activity code.

Comment: Have you already tried something? There's lots of tutorials elsewhere for what you're asking

Comment: @cricket_007 I have trie everythink, almost week of trying. I really tried to get solution, watched all these turotials, but my problem, that I cant implement code into my code. Thats why I raeely search for help

Comment: There's a lot of code here, but I'm not immediately seeing any search related code

Comment: Are there errors in what you tried? What didn't work as expected? How close did you get? Please [edit] your question to include that information

Comment: @cricket_007 I deleted all code, because nothing worked. I saved just my code witch work good, that why here no search code. There wasnt error, just all code red. I have nothing to post, because I havent found nothing that I can implement in my code, I dont know how to do it